# What is the meaning of pri=42

Tags: linux, mount, swap, syntax, priority

When mounting a swap partition on Linux, what does the mount option pri=42 mean?

fstab:

```
/dev/hda1   swap      swap  pri=42       0 0
```

Comment: 42 is obviously a reference to the ultimate question of life, the universe and everything else.

Comment: Or the answer thereto...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not on any linux distro, I believe ubuntu does not set any swap priority by default, some others might.

You may call **man swapon** to the rescue ... here is an excerpt:

> -p priority
>
> Specify the priority of the swap device.  This  option  is only available  if  swapon  was compiled and is used under a 1.3.2 or later kernel.  priority is a value between 0 and 32767. Higher numbers  indicate  higher  priority.  See  swapon(2)  for a full description of swap priorities.  Add  pri=value  to  the option field of /etc/fstab for use with swapon -a.

As a side note, you might wonder why set swap default priority to *42*, I believe it to be just another reference to the [Great Answer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Answer_to_life,_universe_and_everything#Answer_to_Life.2C_the_Universe.2C_and_Everything_.2842.29).

Comment: Thanks, it was a general theory question, so I couldn't specify distro.

Answer (score 1):

The `pri` is short priority and [determines the order in which multiple swap partitions are used](http://www.brighthub.com/computing/linux/articles/37236.aspx).  Partitions with a higher value for `pri` are used first.

Answer (score 0):

assume you have 2 swap-partitions, with 'pri' you can tell the os, which swap partion to use first:

> pri=n     Specifies the swap space priority.  The n variable can
>               be 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, with 0 being lowest priority, and 4
>                 being highest priority.

Comment: where's your source for this?  i'm curious.  note it's not a perfect match as this indicates a max pri=4 and OP's example includes pri=42.

Comment: http://tinyurl.com/yzwsd39

Comment: note, that none of the man pages specify that 42 would be a  legitimate option...

Comment: your link comes from HP's documentation for Compaq Tru64 UNIX v4.0F.  the swapon(8) man page for that product indicates this version doesn't support the *pri* parameter (although it may silently ignore it).

Comment: i am aware of where the quote originates from. i dont see your point yet. the quoted snippet explains the meaning for 'pri' .. the same way it is mentioned in 'man swapon'.

Answer (score 0):

I was on the same boat, and in fairness @avelldiroll answer is already perfect.

But, if you are alone on a terminal with no internet, this is the trail to follow:

1. First you start with `man fstab`, and here the relevant portion:

   > **The fourth field (fs_mntops).**
   >
   > This field describes the mount options associated with the
   > filesystem.
   >
   > It is formatted as a comma-separated list of options. It contains
   > at least the type of mount (ro or rw), plus any additional
   > options appropriate to the filesystem type (including
   > performance-tuning options). For details, see mount(8) or
   > swapon(8).

   Which is suggesting to use `man mount` and `man swapon`.

2. Then you inspect the first of the two, `man mount`, and ... you find nothing ... thus *pri* is not valid for all the file systems
3. Then you inspect the last of the two,  `man swapon`, and (either by scrolling either by searching *fstab*) you'll find this relevant portion:

   > **-p, --priority** *priority*
   >
   > Specify the priority of the swap device. priority is a value between 0    and 32767. Higher numbers indicate
   > higher priority. See swapon(2) for a full description of swap
   > priorities. Add pri=value to the option field of /etc/fstab for use
   > with swapon -a.

I was wondering how I could remember that parameter purely relying on the documentation, turn out is a bit convolute but possible.

By the way, you can have as many swap partitions as you want, the priority is used to prefer a swap partition over another, e.g. this could be the relevant portion on */etc/fstab*

```
...output omitted...
UUID=...   swap    swap  pri=10    0 0
UUID=...   swap    swap  pri=20    0 0
```

(And yes, `pri=42` is definitely a reference to *the answer to life, the universe, and everything* )

Answer (score 0):

One observation.
I have a listing where priority is -2 which I assume is less then 5.

```
swapon -s

Filename                Type        Size    Used    Priority
/dev/sda3               partition   2047996 0       -2
/dev/zram0              partition   1455164 0       5
/dev/zram1              partition   1455164 0       5
```

Linux Mint 20.
This is outside the range 0 to 32767 so that is a conflict with previous Info.